# Getting SQL syntax error while importing table into database using Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am getting the following error while trying to import the table into database using MySQL on my Ubuntu machine.

Error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -u root -p spesh db_hit_type < /var/www/html/spesh.com/public_html/portal/' at line 1

I was using the following command to import the table data.

```
mysql -u root -p spesh db_hit_type < /var/www/html/spesh.com/public_html/portal/js/db_hit_type.sql;
```

Comment: You're somehow passing the command to mysql as though the command itself was the SQL. You tag this as PHP, where does PHP come into this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you try to run this command in MySQL command promt or in some client program. You need to run mysql program from server console, not from mysql console.

Comment: Ok,let me to do that.

Comment: actually i was doing like this `mysql> mysql -u root -p spesh db_hit_type < /var/www/html/spesh.com/public_html/portal/js/db_hit_type.sql;`.

Comment: Yeah, "mysql>" shows that my assumption was right. You need to exit mysql command promt first.

Comment: i exit and did it in server path but its not adding.many helpe messages are showing like `sage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
  -?, --help          Display this help and exit.
  -I, --help          Synonym for -?` etc.

Comment: I think that you specify wrong option "db_hit_type". Mysql import syntax is `mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql` - so if your database name is `spesh`, try `mysql -u root -p spesh  < /var/www/html/spesh.com/public_html/portal/js/db_hit_type.sql`

Comment: I was impoting the table of spesh database.

Comment: @satya yeah, and I think that you should remove `db_hit_type`